# change path for android sdk and avd manager to not point to c:\users

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Is there any way to change this in the android SDK?
It looks like some of the .bat files in the \tools\ folder sets some environment variables but cant tell exactly what they are doing.

I set my windows system profile settings in the registry to point to d:\users and everything else is pointing there but the android sdk keeps wanting to put things in c:\users...

My reasoning for this is I have a much faster drive as my d drive(5 disk raid0) and my system drive is a 5400 spin ide drive...

Comment: see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810478/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-cant-create-avd-in-correct-file-location

Answer (score 11):

I found that adding the environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to windows and pointing it to `d:\users\< myusername >` did the trick.

I changed my user profile folders by editing the registry keys

```
hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

and also the `profileimagepath` under my user's `guid` to point to the d drive
i left the `programdata` folder key alone however.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Control Panel" ⇒ "System" ⇒ (Vista/7) "Advanced system settings" ⇒ Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ "Environment variables" ⇒ Choose "System Variables" for all users" ⇒ Select variable "PATH" ⇒ Choose "Edit" for modifying an existing variable ⇒ In variable "Value", APPEND your \tools directory (e.g., "d:\bin\android-sdk\tools"), followed by a semi-colon ';', IN FRONT of all the existing path entries. DO NOT remove any existing entry; otherwise, some programs may not run after that Add the platform-tools directory to the PATH too.