# Android SDK and AVD Manager -Cant create AVD in correct file location

Tags: android

When trying to create an AVD with the android SDK AVD manager I get 'Error: null'. This keeps happening because the SDK manager is looking for 'List of existing Android Virtual Devices located at \...(wrong location).
How can I change the file location?

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue. I have solved this by setting up the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME in my startup script. The path shall be your desired location of .android folder, excluding the last slash. Example:

```
SET ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Users\toybuilder\Downloads
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem this weekend.  In my case, I was able to create the AVD's, but not able to start them.

The problem was caused by the AVD Manager creating the AVD's in a different directory from where the emulator was trying to launch the AVD's.

In my case, AVD Manager was initially reporting the list of existing Android Virtual Device located at C:\Users\toybuilder\Downloads\.android\avd

It turns out that my Java runtime (in this case, JDK 1.6u24) was reporting C:\Users\toybuilder\Downloads as my home directory (user.home property).   I first confirmed this via Eclipse:

In Eclipse, go to:

Eclipse Menu: Help -> About Eclipse
Click on the [Installation Details]
Click on the [Configuration] tab:
The text box fills with an extended dump of the Eclipse environment .
Look for the user.home value.  In my case, the line read:
user.home=C:\Users\toybuilder\Downloads

It turns out that there's a long-standing [Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931) (nearly 9 years old) on how the Java runtime determine's the user.home property - [as discussed elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338/java-user-home-is-being-set-to-userprofile-and-not-being-resolved)

In my particular case, the buggy behavior was triggered by a bad windows folders redirection.  I had apparently moved my Desktop folder into my Downloads directory at some point by accident.  Although I had fixed the problem, it nevertheless left an entry in my registry with a Desktop folder redirection to the Downloads directory.  There was a HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Desktop registry key that pointed, incorrectly, to C:\Users\toybuilder\Downloads\Desktop

The Java runtime was apparently setting user.home as "Desktop"/.. (i.e., the Downloads directory), while some other mechanisms were resolving the home directory at the correct location (probably the Windows %userprofile% environmental value) -- and hence when the emulator was starting up, it could not find the .android/avd directory, because it was looking from a different starting directory.

After I deleted the incorrect redirection registry key, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Windows with "folder redirection" have this issue. If you are logged in a domain and the admin has set a redirection for your home folders eclipse/android SDK cannot read correctly some files. You can try the following steps:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Just set a user environmental variable like:
   Variable Name:ANDROID_SDK_HOME
   Variable Value:C:\Users\{your login}
3. Copy the .android folder from the "redirection" folder to C:\Users\{your login}
4. Start Eclipse.

Now the AVDs should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Solution for this error:

- Right click Folder "C:\User\yournamecomputer.android" and uncheck Read-Only

it work for me :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable not working for me.
```

1. Open eclipse
2. Click on window menu and then select preference.
3. Select android from left hand side.
4. Now SET SDK location `e.g. E:\android\sdk instead of ../sdk` means set `Absolute path` instead of `Relative path`.

Its worked for me.

I hope this help someone and save time.